# Eclipse template for comment not working (cursor positioning)

Tags: eclipse

I have set the template for "Types" to be:

```
/** $$Id$$
 * $$Author$$
 * $$Revision$$
 *
 * ${cursor}
 */
```

However the `${cursor}` isn't working as it ought to, you can see here ( http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Fconcepts%2Fconcept-template-variables.htm - top of the first table) how `${cursor}` should work.

When I use this template (by typing `/**` and then pressing enter) I get the following (where `|` denotes the cursor position)

```
/**
 * |$Id$
 * $Author$
 * $Revision$
 *
 *
 */
```

How can I fix this, or if I am at fault, how can I get the desired behaviour?

Answer (score 1):

The help does not make it very clear but the variables list you reference only applies to the 'Java > Editor > Templates' templates and not to the 'Java > Code Style > Code Templates'.

There is a much more restricted list for variables for the Code Templates which does not include ${cursor}.

Only the variables shown by the 'Insert Variable...' button of the Edit Template dialog are available.

Comment: Hi! Better late than never. I forgot about this until now. (Some tool is going through my questions) and this helped. Not to be .... "work for it" but if the tick is any motivation I'd love a link to the source. Sorry for late reply. Hope you are well!